# Differences between ngCordova's $cordovaMedia and $cordovaNativeAudio

Tags: cordova, audio, local-storage, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

I'm looking into implementing audio into my Ionic Cordova/PhoneGap hybrid application. The app will retain about 3 hours of audio and is intended to be played "on-the-go" where the audio can play in the background with a locked screen regardless of platform. In addition, implementation is likely to include a Spotify-ish offline download to device feature.

This being said, while read through the ngCordova documentation I came across two plugins that I am having a hard time distinguishing the difference between `$cordovaNativeAudio` and  `$cordovaMedia`.

Their descriptions are as follows.

> ## **$cordovaNativeAudio**
>
> > This Cordova / PhoneGap (3.5+) plugin enables concurrency (multi-channel playback), polyphony (multi-voice playback) and
> >     minimized latency (via caching) in audio-based applications, by
> >     leveraging native audio APIs. Designed for the use in HTML5-based
> >     cross-platform games and mobile/hybrid audio applications.
>
> ## **$cordovaMedia**
>
> > This plugin provides the ability to record and play back audio files
> >     on a device.
> >
> > **A note on iOS capabilities:**
> >
> > An app that **plays or records audio continuously (even while the app is
> >     running in the background)** can register to perform those tasks in the
> >     background. You enable audio support from the Background modes section
> >     of the Capabilities tab in your Xcode project. (You can also enable
> >     this support by including the UIBackgroundModes key with the audio
> >     value in your app’s Info.plist file.) Apps that play audio content in
> >     the background must play audible content and not silence.

My first impression is that `$cordovaNativeAudio` best suites my needs, as it caches and as the name implies it is "native audio" and would play from the device's filesystem. However, looking more into `$cordovaMedia` it seems to do the same, and more, with support for video and recording (not necessary but nice to have), and the documentation spesifically says audio "*plays ... continuously (even while the app is
running in the background)*" which is what I'm looking for. However the note before make mention that's a "iOS capability" and makes no mention to Android. Does this include Android? Could someone explain the real differences between the two? And maybe some Advantages or disadvantages of these two different approaches?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use $cordovaNativeAudio to play downloaded audio files.
It only plays files bundled with your app (residing under your www/audio or similar). 
Just look at the [Java source code implementation for Android](https://github.com/SidneyS/cordova-plugin-nativeaudio/blob/239e9f1c671df4accb424787f2d337181c7cc446/src/android/NativeAudio.java) and notice that it even adds "www/" to the path.
It is unfortunate, because it works really well and has a nice API.

$cordovaMedia has lots of issues (see [ionic forum discussion on the subject](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/problem-of-download-audio-file-and-play-this-audio/16188/)), but that is the only choice, short of writing your own plugin.

Answer (score 0):

A big problem with the $cordovaMedia is that callbacks are not implemented for any platforms except Android, FireOS, and Windows.  So if you want this to run on iOS, you can still play the media, you just won't be able to tell when it stops playing the media...

See: [cordova-plugin-media callback methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33558012/cordova-plugin-media-callback-methods/33568340#33568340) for more details.