# cordova-plugin-media callback methods

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

I am using cordova-media-plugin 1.0.1. in an Ionic mobile app.  I am using the plugin to play the audio file.

I am able to get it to play using:

```html
var media = $cordovaMedia.newMedia(fileToPlay,
           // success callback
          mediaSuccess,

          // error callback
          mediaFailure,

          // status callback
          mediaStatus
        );
```

I can then call media.play() at it plays the file.

However, the callbacks never seem to execute.  I have them defined as:

```html
 function mediaSuccess () {
      console.log("Successfully finished task.");
    }
      
    function mediaFailure (err) {
      console.log("An error occurred: " + err.code);
    }

    function mediaStatus (status) {
      console.log("A status change occurred: " + status.code);
    }
```

But they are never called.   However, it my console, I am seeing logging from the player itself as it starts and stops playing:

```html
Will attempt to use file resource '//var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/931BFA01-CDA4-43CD-BC16-7FB6A64305DC/Library/NoCloud/DateTime-1446772191539audio_007.wav'

Playing audio sample '//var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/931BFA01-CDA4-43CD-BC16-7FB6A64305DC/Library/NoCloud/DateTime-1446772191539audio_007.wav'

Stopped playing audio sample '//var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/931BFA01-CDA4-43CD-BC16-7FB6A64305DC/Library/NoCloud/DateTime-1446772191539audio_007.wav'
```

These logging events are going to the console, but they are NOT in my code so they must be coming from the media object.

I need to get the status change and/or success call backs as I need to update the model to enable the play but again when the clip finishes play.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I am working with android, and seems that none of the callbacks are fired!

Comment: did any of you have success on this issue? or did you switch to another plugin that really supports callbacks? I just tried with cordova-plugin-media 2.1.0 (on iOS 9.3.2) and still the same problem..

Answer (score 3):

After digging into this deeper, I have found that (despite the documentation) callbacks are not implemented for iOS in version 1.0.1 of the cordova-media-plugin.  They are implemented for Android, FireOS, and Windows ONLY.

At the bottom of the Media.js file in the module's www directory, it creates a cordova channel which lets it subscribe to messages from the native player.  Unfortunately, that code is only executed for android, fireos, and windows phone:

```html
if (cordova.platformId === 'android' || cordova.platformId === 'amazon-fireos' || cordova.platformId === 'windowsphone') {

    var channel = require('cordova/channel');

    channel.createSticky('onMediaPluginReady');
    channel.waitForInitialization('onMediaPluginReady');

    channel.onCordovaReady.subscribe(function() {
        exec(onMessageFromNative, undefined, 'Media', 'messageChannel', []);
        channel.initializationComplete('onMediaPluginReady');
    });
}
```

I tried adding ios to the list to see if it was just a miss in that code and it blew up:

ERROR: Method 'messageChannel:' not defined in Plugin 'Media'

So... those of us building for iOS or other non-Android/Windows platforms are SOL when it comes to callbacks (though playing still works).  There seems to be no way to submit a bug report to Apache about this unless it is an email coming from an apache.org email address, so I am not sure they even know about it.