# Cordova plugin media doesn't fire onStatus callbacks on ios 11.0 and 12.0 properly

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a project built on ionic 4.2.1. The project is developed for ios and uses audio playing. First I tried @ionic-native/media lib for tracking statuses (I actually need only two of them - 'started' and 'stoped'), and tested in browser it all worked good, but on ios there is a big problem.

At first time I play audio there are no callback at all.
The second one - just after I clicked the button two callback are fired at the same time - start and stop.
After that, the second case is repeated all the next times. Audio is playing properly all the time though.

I tried to use cordova-plugin-media itself, without @ionic-native/media, but the problem is in cordova plugin and nothing changed.

Tested on ios 11.x and 12.1
ionic 4.2.1
cordova-plugin-media ^5.0.1
@ionic-native/media ^4.17.0

with pure cordova-media-plugin

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {

    let file = new (<any>window).Media(path, 
      () => { 
        console.log("playAudio():Audio Success")
      },
      (err) => { 
        console.log("playAudio():Audio Error: " + err)
      },
      (status) => {
        this.addConsole('status=' + status)
        if (status === 1) {
          this.isAudioActive = true
          this.addConsole('played')
        }

        if (status === 4) {
          this.addConsole('stoped')
          this.isAudioActive = false
        }
      }
    )
    this.file = file
    this.file.play()
  })
```

with @ionic-native/media

```
  let file: MediaObject = this.media.create(path);
  this.file = file
  this.addConsole('play')
  this.file.play()
  this.file.onStatusUpdate.subscribe(
    (status) => {
      this.addConsole('status=' + status)
      if (status === 1) {
        this.isAudioActive = true
        this.addConsole('played')
      }

      if (status === 4) {

        this.addConsole('stoped')
        this.isAudioActive = false
      }
    }
  )
```

Hope since [cordova-plugin-media callback methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33558012/cordova-plugin-media-callback-methods) anything has changed

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Same problem but only with iOS.